# Signability fails test for windows driver

Tags: driver, signing

This is the .inf file. It is just a sample from
 https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/bitmap

I have all the 3 files bitmap.DLL, bitmap.ini,bitmap.gdp all in the same folder at C:\windows. 
Why does it complain about bitmap.gdp and bitmap.ini

I am getting this error:

```
Errors:


 22.9.1: bitmap.gdp in [bitmapgdp] of Driver Package1\bitmap.inf is missing or cannot be decompressed from source media.  Please verify all path values specified in SourceDisksNames, SouceDisksFiles, and CopyFiles sections resolve to the actual location of the file, and are expressed in terms relative to the location of the inf.

 22.9.1: bitmap.ini in [bitmapini] of Driver Package1\bitmap.inf is missing or can
not be decompressed from source media.  Please verify all path values specified in SourceDisksNames, SouceDisksFiles, and CopyFiles sections resolve to the actual location of the file, and are expressed in terms relative to the location of the inf.
; bitmap.INF
;
; INF file for bitmap Driver
; - for Windows XP (SP2), NT2003 (R2), Vista, Win7, NT2008 (x86 and x64)
;
; Copyright 2007-2010 MS

[Version]
Signature="$windows NT$"
ClassGUID={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer
Provider=MS
DriverVer=04/21/2010, 5.0.10.4211505
catalogfile = bitmapnew.cat


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Manufacturer Section
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[Manufacturer]
"Microsoft"=Microsoft, NTx86, NTamd64, NTia64, NTarm64


[Microsoft]
"Bitmap Driver"      = BITMAP

[Microsoft.NTx86]
"Bitmap Driver"      = BITMAP

[Microsoft.NTamd64]
"Bitmap Driver"      = BITMAP

[Microsoft.NTia64]
"Bitmap Driver"      = BITMAP

[Microsoft.NTarm64]
"Bitmap Driver"      = BITMAP


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Models Section
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[bitmapGDP]
bitmap.GDP


[bitmapINI]
bitmap.INI

[bitmapDLL]
bitmap.DLL


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Install Section
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[BITMAP]
CopyFiles=bitmapGDP,bitmapINI,bitmapDLL
DataSection=UNIDRV_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=UNIDRV.OEM,UNIDRV_DATA



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Source Media Section
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=66000



[SourceDisksFiles]
bitmap.DLL = 1,
bitmap.GDP = 1,
bitmap.INI = 1

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%, 
2= %CWIN%


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Control Flags Section
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Strings Section
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[Strings]
DiskName="Disk Drive",
CWIN = "C:\Windows\bitmap"
```

Comment: did you follow the guide here? https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples

Comment: In the Version section, add a reference to a catalog file that matches the .INF name like this: CatalogFile=XpsDrvSmpl.cat

In the SourceDisksFiles section, change the location of the DLL files you are building, to =1. This indicates that there is no architecture specific directory in this driver. If you ship multiple architectures simultaneously, you will need to collate the driver INF manually.

Comment: @Baget: I didn't read with the sense of being architecture specific. We have a legacy driver built by someone 15 years back and now I am in the attempts to port it. I have never written driver in my life. Just googling and reading I was able to build it just for x86 configurations. x64 I am Warning C4267 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data
I have no idea how to fix that except that DWORD is 32. I will visit this again. As of now I am foucssing on understanding how to sign the x86 driver, install and add connect our application to the driver.

Comment: @Baget: I will have to come to back to the architecture specific configurations. But for now install the x86 one on my x64 computer. This is just for development learning.

Comment: @Baget:Can you tell me what this means. This is in the legacy driver and I don't understand what is Root. How can I make a i386 in Visual studio. [SourceDisksNames.x86]
1 = "Root",,,"i386"

[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1 = "Root",,,"x64"

Comment: you can refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-sourcedisksnames-section

Comment: @Baget: I got past that issue. I turned on detailed verbose logging in VS and that helped. Can you may be help me with this please or anyone you know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125988/legacy-print-driver-is-fuzzy